# dot (.) or source behavior in bash when POSIX mode set (OS X)

Tags: bash, osx, posix

I tried to check the difference in behavior of the `.` (or equivalently `source`) built-in. I'm using bash 3.2 on El Capitan. According to the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-POSIX-Mode.html), setting the POSIX mode (`set -o posix`) should avoid the shell searching in current directory when `.` is issued with a filename not containing `/`.

I'm in tmp directory where myscript.sh (which echoes "Hello") resides:

```
MacBook:tmp simone$ set | grep SHELLOPTS
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor
MacBook:tmp simone$ . myscript.sh 
Hello
MacBook:tmp simone$ set -o posix
MacBook:tmp simone$ set | grep SHELLOPTS
SHELLOPTS=braceexpand:emacs:hashall:histexpand:history:interactive-comments:monitor:posix
MacBook:tmp simone$ . myscript.sh 
Hello
```

It appears that the script in current directory is executed irrespectively of the POSIX setting. Did I misunderstand something or is there a more subtle explanation?

---

As pointed out in the comments, the behavior should be as described if `.` isn't in the PATH. My PATH variable contains the following string:

`/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: According to the docs you link: "The . and source builtins do not search the current directory for the filename argument __if it is not found by searching PATH__".  Is `.` in your `PATH`?

Comment: @SatōKatsura, I've added details in the post.

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Bash 4.4 on OpenBSD (allows for sourcing the script without path if not in POSIX mode, but won't find it in POSIX mode). Bash 4.4 on macOS Sierra can't find the file no matter if POSIX mode is enabled or not. Bash 3.2 on macOS Sierra (from the base system) behaves as you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that was fixed in a subsequent version. From the [bash changelog](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES):

> This document details the changes between this version, bash-4.0-alpha,
>   and the previous version, bash-3.2-release. (…)
>
> 1.  Changes to Bash (…)
>
> ggg. Fixed a bug that caused a shell running in Posix mode to search `$PWD` for a file specified as an argument to `source`/`.` when the file was not found in `$PATH`. (…)
>
> iii. Fixed a bug that caused the shell to search `$PATH` for an argument to
>        `source`/`.` even when it contained a `/`.